# How to queue multiple calls (via AJAX) to FileStream / StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, model-view-controller, locking

Sorry if the title isn't quite correct, not 100% sure what I am looking for.

I have some code doing the following:

```
public static ProcessData()
{
    AddNewData()
    GetAllData()
    BuildTSV();
    Send();
}
```

It's an MVC web app, ProcessData is an Ajax call passing in some form data. AddNewData writes to a db it's a simple call to a stored proc that does a basic INSERT. GetAllData queries the db, it's a simple SELECT statement on a single table. BuildTSV constructs a file using the db data, and then we send it to a remote server.

If BuildTSV is hit in quick enough in succession, I get file locking problems (not the database). BuildTSV is using a simple StreamWriter.

I cannot change this workflow, I'd like to somehow pool the AddNewData() calls and then only carry on once they've all finished.

Threading? Queues? BlockingCollection? Wait if the file is locked and try again?

This is all new to me and struggling to make sense of the 1001 different approaches.

Comment: _"I'd like to somehow pool the AddNewData() calls and then only carry on once they've all finished."_ - even if you do this, what happens when you decide that they've all finished, but one more comes in? or two more? I'm thinking that your method for accepting this data might be incorrect. Without the implementation of `AddNewData` and `GetAllData` I can't say for sure.

Comment: AddNewData is a simple call to a stored proc that is nothing more than a straight forward INSERT. GetAllData is the same just selecting the data. Single table, a few columns.

Comment: If it's a simple INSERT, where are the locking problems coming from?

Comment: in BuildTSV. I have to pull the data from the table and upload it as TSV to a remote server. When constructing the TSV, if a second request comes in quick enough the file is locked.

Comment: Do you have to write to the TSV in the same file location every time, or could you just use a unique temporary file for each call?

Comment: a temp / multiple files would work. I delete the CSV once it;s been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I created a tiny service to handle this.

I would query the database and keep track of the number of rows in a table. If this was incremented, I'd select all the data and process it into a flat file then send. This runs every couple of minutes and solved all of my issues.

I followed [this as a starting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) point, and essentially dumped my existing code responsible for pulling the data into a flat file then sending, alongside some added logging and an email notification for when the service stopped.